# trying to do each function on a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey community im doing this centering of pictures in a frame so the center of the image is in the center of the frame despite its size. (frame is fixed)

```
 $('.item-box').each(function () {
    var fwidth = $('.gmask').width();
    var iwidth = $('.gmask img').width();
    var fheight = $('.gmask').height();
    var iheight = $('.gmask img').height();

    $('.gmask img').css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth - iwidth) / 2) - 3);
    $('.gmask img').css('margin-top', Math.floor((fheight - iheight) / 2) - 3);
});
```

I wanna do this as a loop for each of my '.item-box' can anyone tell me what im doing wrong

*EDIT

btw im doing jquery template

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl "> 
    {{for Product}}

    <div class="item-box" id="{{if #index < 5 }}itemboxTeaser{{else}}itemboxRest{{/if}}{{:#index+1}}">
        <div class="visual-gallery">
            <div class="gmask">
                <ul class="replaceClass">
                    <a href="/lejemaal/{{:Urlname}}/#/Lejemaal">
                        <img src="{{:PhysicalPathToFrontPhotoUseWebFront300Px}}" alt="">
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     {{/for}}
</script>
```

Comment: Provide us the HTML markup as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose `.gmask` and it's relative `img` are children of `$(this)` (your `.item-box`)
**Try like:**

```
$('.item-box').each(function () {
        var $gmask = $(this).find('.gmask');
        var $gmaskImg = $gmask.find('img');

        var fwidth = $gmask.width();
        var iwidth = $gmaskImg.width();
        var fheight = $gmask.height();
        var iheight = $gmaskImg.height();

        $gmaskImg.css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth - iwidth) / 2) - 3);
        $gmaskImg.css('margin-top', Math.floor((fheight - iheight) / 2) - 3);
});
```

**EDIT after reading OP comment**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.item-box').find('.gmask').each(function () {
            var $gmask = $(this);
            var $gmaskImg = $gmask.find('img');

            var fwidth = $gmask.width();
            var iwidth = $gmaskImg.width();
            var fheight = $gmask.height();
            var iheight = $gmaskImg.height();

            $gmaskImg.css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth - iwidth) / 2) - 3);
            $gmaskImg.css('margin-top', Math.floor((fheight - iheight) / 2) - 3);
    });
});
```

Comment: .gmask is my frame width 200px height 200px, .img is a child of that, .item-box is my list of products

Comment: i guess i need to wait until the jquery template are done generating all nodes and then do my each function?? cause when i console.log inside my script it post nothing like it don't get initiated

Comment: @SimonPertersen Sure. You need to wrap my code into a `$(window).load(function(){ /*HERE*/ });` to wait for the images to load

Comment: sorry for the late reply, its still not getting loaded i even post a console.log as the first of the function to check if it get initiated

Comment: @SimonPertersen What is not getting loaded? have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16035/discussion-between-simon-pertersen-and-roko)

Comment: its a jsrender thats executing it and thats are rendering it after the window is loaded is their a way to do the js render simultaneously with our script

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to center the image inside each .item-box, so you need to refer to 'this' :

```
 $('.item-box').each(function () {
    var fwidth = $(this).find('.gmask').width();
    var iwidth = $(this).find('.gmask img').width();
    var fheight = $(this).find('.gmask').height();
    var iheight = $(this).find('.gmask img').height();

    $(this).find('.gmask img').css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth - iwidth) / 2) - 3);
    $(this).find('.gmask img').css('margin-top', Math.floor((fheight - iheight) / 2) - 3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are taking the first element of the page, whatever the current .item-box :

```
var fwidth = $('.gmask').width();
var iwidth = $('.gmask img').width();
var fheight = $('.gmask').height();
var iheight = $('.gmask img').height();
```

You need to do `$(this).find('.element');`

Answer (score 0):

Since the img is what you're after, why not `.each`-loop over those elements?

```
$('.item-box .gmask img').each(function ()
{
    var parent, fwidth,fheight,iwidth,iheight;
    parent = $(this);
    while(!parent.attr('class').match(/\bgmask\b/))
    {//get the .gmask parent of current img
        parent = parent.parent();
    }
    iwidth = $(this).width();
    iheight = $(this).height;
    fwidth = parent.width();
    fheight = parent.height();
    $(this).css('margin-left', Math.floor((fwidth - iwidth) / 2) - 3);
    $(this).css('margin-top', Math.floor((fheight - iheight) / 2) - 3);
});
```

This reduces the amount of selectors used, thus increasing overall performance. IMHO, it's also easier to read and maintain.